# Mirror size and pixel resolution on planetary surfaces

Tags: mars, camera, hirise, resolution

MRO’s HiRise camera has a 0.5m primary mirror and a per-pixel resolution of ~30cm from an altitude of 200km. For an identical orbit, and ignoring any atmospheric effects, what mirror size would be needed for a resolution of 0.25 m/px?

Comment: It does sound like an exam question, but it’s not

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question does not make optical sense (as currently asked) and does not have a numerical answer.

Aperture size affects the diffraction limit, but pixel size is an independent choice, and you need the ratio of the distance to target and *telescope focal length*, not the aperture size, to get resolution in meters/pixel.

One might assume that the designers set the pixel size to roughly something like one half the diffraction limit, but that's wavelength dependent which is a big factor for some systems that operate over a very wide range of wavelengths.

It also depends on the [shape of the aperture, and type & size of obstructions](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/51978/7982)

If you'd like to update the question I'm happy to update this answer.

Comment: WorldView-3’s IOC deliver 30 cm imagery with telescope primary mirror diameter of 110 cm  https://www.eoportal.org/satellite-missions/worldview-3#learning-on-the-job